# Embedded Facebook feed on website not possible after Graph Api 2.5?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-iframe, facebook-feed

I've been coding a website using and modifying Bootstrap template. End of summer I left the site as it was, but once returning there recently I noticed the Facebook activity feed (newests posts and such) had dissappeared from my front page. Reading from Facebook Developers; after the release of Graph Api 2.5 adding Facebook feed on your website is no longer possible? Is there any other way to get the Facebook feed back on the site? I had been using iframe on my site while it was still working.

Comment: The Page plugin can display the five most current posts of a page. Other than that, you’d have to go read the feed yourself via API and display the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main steps involved in embedding Facebook page feed in your website- 1. Getting Facebook Access Token, 2. Calling the Graph API passing the access token.

**1. Getting the access token** - Here is the step by step process to get the access token for your Facebook page. - [Embed Facebook page feed on my website](http://www.logicalfeed.com/posts/1170/Embed-facebook-page-feed-on-my-website). As per this you need to create an app in Facebook developers page which would give you an App Id and an App Secret. Use these two and get the Access Token.

**2. Calling the Graph API** - This would be pretty simple once you get the access token. You just need to form a URL to Graph API with all the fields/properties you want to retrieve and make a GET request to this URL. Here is one example on how to do it in asp.net MVC. [Embedding facebook feeds using asp.net mvc](http://www.logicalfeed.com/posts/1172/Embedding-facebook-feeds-using-asp-net-mvc). This should be pretty similar in any other technology as it would be just a HTTP GET request.

**Sample FQL Query:** `https://graph.facebook.com/FBPageName/posts?fields=full_picture,picture,link,message,created_time&limit=5&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE`